Usual method for checkout fields in WooCommerce does not work
My shop is a "name your price" only to deliver files to the users of my free tutorials.
So checkout page has to be as light as possible, removing those useless fields.
I am using the snippet below that seems to have no effect.
It is executed via a snippet plugin. The fields remain.
Step 2 : when it works, I will display the email fields only if a donation is made (so when the price is greater than 0).
Note that I added just echo "Download"; to be sure that the code is executed, and it is...
I tested 'required' argument set to false, to see if it change something, but it didn't work.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_remove_woo_checkout_fields' );
 
function custom_remove_woo_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    
    echo "Download"; // Just for testing
    
    // remove billing fields
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_first_name']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_last_name']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_1']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_city']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_phone']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_email']);
   
    // remove shipping fields 
    unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_first_name']);    
    unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_last_name']);  
    unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_company']);
    unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_address_1']);
    unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_address_2']);
    unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_city']);
    unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_postcode']);
    unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_country']);
    unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_state']);
    
    // remove order comment fields
    unset($fields['order']['order_comments']);  
    
  // remove billing fields required
    $fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['required'] = false;
    $fields['billing']['billing_last_name']['required'] = false;
    $fields['billing']['billing_company']['required'] = false;
    $fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['required'] = false;
    $fields['billing']['billing_address_2']['required'] = false;
    $fields['billing']['billing_city']['required'] = false;
    $fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['required'] = false;
    $fields['billing']['billing_country']['required'] = false;
    $fields['billing']['billing_state']['required'] = false;
    $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['required'] = false;
    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['required'] = false;
   
    // remove shipping fields required
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_first_name']['required'] = false;    
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_last_name']['required'] = false;  
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_company']['required'] = false;
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_address_1']['required'] = false;
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_address_2']['required'] = false;
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_city']['required'] = false;
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_postcode']['required'] = false;
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_country']['required'] = false;
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_state']['required'] = false;
       
    $fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['required'] = false;
    
    return $fields;
}


You need to switch back to WooCommerce Classic Cart / Checkout.

Thanks Loic, now the fields are still here but empty ...

It works with your other post that adds php generated css :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66202272/how-to-remove-all-woocommerce-checkout-billing-fields-without-errors
